# Integrate function without specifying limits of integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've been having trouble to make mathematica evaluate an integral without specifying the values of the limits of integration. I mean, if I write

```
Integrate[x,{x,x1,x2}]
```

Mathematica returns the correct answer: $\frac{(x2)^2-(x1)^2}{2}$. But If I write something like

```
Integrate[x^2/(1-x),{x,x1,x2}]
```

Mathematica just keeps the evaluation forever...

Is there something that I can do to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Consider what happens when x1 <= 1 <= x2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral doesn't converge everywhere, see @belisarius comment, so tell `Integrate` what constraints you have on `x1` and `x2` via the `Assumptions` option:

```
Integrate[x^2/(1 - x), {x, x1, x2}, Assumptions -> 1 < x1 < x2 || x1 < x2 < 1]
(* 1/2 (x1 - x2) (2 + x1 + x2) + Log[1 - x1] - Log[1 - x2] *)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. I din't know that I had to specify that, but obviously it makes perfect sense. Thank you